# Why is my function returning 0 when when I try to give it arguments by replacement?

Tags: functions, evaluation

I tried running a function `f` with rules and calling it directly with arguments specified directly but the one with rules returns zero while the one with direct arguments returns sensible answers (and what I expected).

The definition of `f` is:

```
f[x,t1,t2,c] := Sum[c[[k2]], Exp[ -Norm[aL2[x, t1]] - t2[[k2]], 2]^2, {k2, 1, Length[t2]}]
```

First I tried evaluating it with rules:

```
f[x,c,t2L, t1L]] /. {x -> 1, t2L->{2}, t2L-> {3}, c->{4}}
```

and got:

[image]

and I tried tracing it to see whats going on, but can't figure it out why the trace has a random zero at the end. I called:

```
Trace[f[x,c,t2L, t1L]] /. {x -> 1, t2L->{2}, t2L-> {3}, c->{4}}]
```

but got:

[image]

However, when I call the function directly with arguments:

```
f[1,{4},{3},{2}]
```

I get what I expected:

[image]

anyone know what is going on?

---

I apologize if this is a easy question, but I've read so much about *Mathematica* at this point without getting anywhere that I don't know what else to do except ask someone what the issue is.

Comment: Please post Mathematica input code directly instead of inserting screenshots of code (screenshots of the behavior is fine, e,g, the last screenshot you've included). By the way, I'm pretty sure that the `Sum` is trying to evaluate before you are substituting for `t2L`: then, since `Length[t2L] = 0` (because `t2L` is a symbol), the `Sum` will evaluate to `0` because it is not summing over anything.

Comment: You do not specify what the definition of `f` is and you do not give code except as (bizarrely blurry) screenshots. Probably your question can be answered straightforwardly, but you will need to ask it in a way that is more conducive to receiving help. For now, I vote to close it, since without `f`, the whole thing is meaningless.

Comment: @march I have edited my question with valid code. Is my question approvable now or how can I further improve it? Am I missing anything else to reach the standards of the site?

Comment: IMO, that's better. Sometimes it's the case that it is easy to see that a user has made a standard error. More often, it is necessary to see the user's code to see where-the-error-is/why-the-output-is-wrong/etc. So we like to see definitions of symbols/function you are using. We also like to see copy-and-pastable Mathematica code (it makes it easier for us to help). Finally, it's nice to see effort toward a solution, which you've done. Unfortunately, I do not have the rep to vote to re-open. However: your question has been answered below. And I think your code has errors beyond yielding 0.

Answer (score 4):

I can illustrate what is going on with a simpler function than yours. Consider

```
f[x_, y_] := Sum[y[[i]], {i, Length[x]}
```

Then `f[{"a", "b"}, {3, 4}]` gives `7` as expected, but

```
f[x, y] /. {x -> {"a", "b"}, y -> {3, 4}}
```

gives `0`, just as your function did. Now `/.` is infix operator version of `ReplaceAll`, so the above is equivalent of

```
ReplaceAll[f[x, y], {x -> {"a", "b"}, y -> {3, 4}}] (* 1 *)
```

`ReplaceAll` uses standard evaluation, which means all it arguments get evaluated before anything else is done. So `f[x, y]` gets evaluated before the substitution is done. And what does `f[x, y]` evaluate to?

```
f[x, y]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

because `Length[x]` in `Sum[y[[i]], {i, Length[x]}]` is 0 and `Sum[y[[i]], {i, 0]}]` is identically 0.

So the expression tagged with `(* 1 *)` is same as

```
ReplaceAll[0, {x -> {"a", "b"}, y -> {3, 4}}]
```

which, of course, returns 0.

How can you get what you want? You can use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) to delay evaluation.

```
Unevaluated[f[x, y]] /. {x -> {"a", "b"}, y -> {3, 4}}
```

> ```
>  7
> ```